# `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` reports clicks when mouse is not clicked

Tags: python, mouse, pygame

I am programming an experiment with Pygame 1.9.2 on Python 2.7. In the experiment, I display an image and ask the user to click either the left mouse button or right mouse button based on a feature of the image (I instruct them in advance when to click what). The image is displayed until the user clicks or if the time of image display exceeds a fixed duration.

Here's the code snippet.(Hope this bit is enough to understand what is being done.)

```
pygame.display.update()
resp = None
while 1:
    dispEnd = time.time()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)    
    pygame.event.get()
    ms = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()            
    if ms[0] or ms[2]:
        rt = dispEnd - dispSt                
        if ms[0]:
            resp = 'Yes'
        else:
            resp = 'No'
        break
    if dispEnd - dispSt >= changeDuration:
        break
```

This piece of code is part of a bigger loop where an image is selected and displayed, so this runs several times.

What happens at unpredictable times is that the program does not wait for user input. Right after displaying the image, it enters the while loop and proceeds as if the mouse were pressed.

It's a random error and happens anytime; sometimes right at the start of the program, from the very first run of the loop; so probably it is not because of the event queue possibly not being cleared (which it is while calling `pygame.event.get()`) and it also cannot be defaulting to the previous mouse click; sometimes it happens after a few iterations of the loop. Either way, it is disastrous for an experiment.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `event.get()` and then just discarding the result. Shouldn't you be doing `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` somewhere if you want to detect whether the mouse was pressed?

Comment: Well, I'm using `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` to get the mouse buttons that were pressed. I am calling `pygame.mouse.get()` because the documentation says "Note, remember to call pygame.event.get - get events from the queue before this function. Otherwise it will not work." And, it does not work if it's not called.

Comment: Show error messages (trackback)

Comment: I don't see rest of your code but I think that using `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: if event.button == 1 or event.button == 3` you will don't need `while 1:` and `dispEnd`, `dispSt`, `changeDuration`, `time.time()` and `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`. It seem to me that you try to "reinvent the wheel"

Comment: @furas Apologies for the delay in reply. There is no error message. It's a logical error in flow of the experiment. And, the `time.time()` is used because it I need to break out of the loop on either one of two events, a mouse button press or if time has exceeded `changeDuration`. And, I will try using the alternative you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
...
while 1:
    dispEnd = time.time()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
            #do something           
    ...
```